# Method when() from Mockito do not work correctly

Tags: spring, testing, model-view-controller, junit, mockito

I have problem with mockito method: when(...). When I test:

> afterThrowExceptionShouldReturnCorrectHttpStatus()

Ran first, then the second test:

> controllerShouldReturnListOfAnns()

It always fails because it throw NotFoundException. When I delete the first test or running second test as first, then everything is correct. This look like method when() from first test override method when() form the second test   There is test code and test configuration.

```
@ActiveProfiles("dev")
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest
public class AnnTestController {

@Autowired
private AnnounService annSrv;
@Autowired
private AnnounRepo annRepo;
@Autowired
private WebApplicationContext wac;
private MockMvc mockMvc;

@Before
public void contextLoads() {
    this.mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders.webAppContextSetup(wac).build();
}


@Test
public void afterThrowExceptionShouldReturnCorrectHttpStatus() throws Exception {
    when(this.annRepo.getAnnounList()).thenThrow(NotFoundAnnounException.class);
    this.mockMvc.perform(get("/ann/list")).andExpect(status().isNotFound());
}


@Test
public void controllerShouldReturnListOfAnns() throws Exception {
    List<Announcement> lst = new ArrayList<>();
    lst.add(new Announcement(1, "test", "test"));
    when(annRepo.getAnnounList()).thenReturn(lst);
  this.mockMvc.perform(get("/ann/list"))
 .andExpect(status().isOk())
 .andExpect(jsonPath("$[0].id", is(1)));
}}
```

Config:

```
@Profile("dev")
@Configuration
public class BeanConfig {


@Bean
public CommentsRepo commentsRepo() {
    return mock(CommentsRepo.class);
}}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try somthing like that:

```
 @After public void reset_mocks() {
    Mockito.reset(this.annRepo);
 }
```

Comment: This is working! Thank you! btw. why this problem occurs? Is it normal to adding always this method ( @After)?

Comment: The lifecycle of your spring tests is controlled by the Spring Runner.
The Spring runner does not take care of the Mockito lifecycle.
So you have to manage it yourself